# CSS, making header and footer keep 100% width on browser resize

Tags: css, footer

I've almost got this figured out by using previous questions, but I'm running into a small problem.

I need my header and footer to span 100% of the page when I resize the browser, and I've solved this for the most part by using min-width on the header and footer. The header is behaving very well, but the footer has a little white space on the right at all times. Help?
NOTE: The white space only occurs on browser resize (getting smaller), and it is equally spaced at all times.

```
html,
body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
   min-width:1100px;
   }
#body {
  padding:10px;
  padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
 }
#footer {
 position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
  background:#6cf;
   min-width:1100px;
}

<div id="container">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="body"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I've changed min-width in the footer to be 1120px as a bandaid solution, and it's working for the moment. Why is this working??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem's that you set `padding:10px;` and `min-width:1100px;` on your header while you define `min-width:1100px;` on your footer. That is causing you your white space.

Try something like this instead:
http://jsfiddle.net/hrkp6/

Comment: Thanks. This solves it. Also, any idea why if too much content is added in the body it causes my footer to not sink to the bottom?

Comment: for this you need a sticky footer. It will never do that beacuse its position is absolute.

Answer (score 1):

The padding in your header is screwing you up here.

I removed it and gave it a fixed height for this demo...

http://jsfiddle.net/BA2UY/

It's because `padding` is *added* to the dimensions of the element which makes it wider than you specify.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
#footer {
 position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height:60px;   
  background:#6cf;
  /* get rid of min-width */
}
```

Comment: whhat happens when the content overlaps the  footer?

Comment: -- Nope, sorry, it doesn't work. It brings me to the problem I had before, which is if I resize the browser, there is an ugly whitespace on scroll-over.
Thanks for the input though.

Comment: The same thing that would happen with your current code, either appear on top or on the bottom depending on the z-index.

Comment: Nothing wrong with having a `min-width` here... it will simply make a scrollbar instead of messing up its content.

Comment: Yeah I know, but my header is working just fine at the moment. I'm curious as to why my footer is acting differently?

Comment: Consider using the free plug-ins [firebug][1] + [firepath][2] to further characterize the problem.  This common combo of tools will help you to interrogate web page layout and see the css that is contributing to sections of the display. 


  [1]: http://getfirebug.com/
  [2]: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/

Comment: @dylandrop, my comment was addressed to the author of the answer.  See my answer, your padding in the header is your root problem.

Comment: dont use the body twice. You already have a body element. rename to such as content